# MongoDB all find method undefined

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony

I inserted some data into the database but my issue is when I want to retreive it.

I followed the official documentation with `findOneById` method, `findAll` method and I getting the following error

`Attempted to call an undefined method named "findAll" of class "Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Query\Builder`

My controler is like below:

```
$export = $this
            ->get('doctrine_mongodb')
            ->getManager()
            ->createQueryBuilder('NeoNasaBundle:Neorepo');
        $aff = $export->findAll();
```

I need to finish a project before tonight and It becomes trickly...

If you want some detail, I will EDIT this post

Thanks for support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using the latest `DoctrineMongoDBBundler`then you should be accessing `find()`, `findOneById()`, `findOneByName()` or `findAll()` through a repository object. Using your example:

```
$export = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')
               ->getManager()
               ->getRepository('NeoNasaBundle:Neorepo')
$aff = > $export->findAll();
```

If this doesn't help, you need to provide version of Doctrine and MongoDB.

Comment: Oh thanks. It's that... how to loose 4 hours on a stupid problem :)